# It possible to Select all childs of first parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to know a CSS selector that I need to use to select only all child of first parent.

```
<div class="seasonbar">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="seasonbar">
  <a href="#">E 1</a>
  <a href="#">E 2</a>
  <a href="#">E 3</a>
</div>
```

As result, I want only select all links of the first `.seasonbar`

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: `.seasonbar:first-child *` ?

Comment: No ! It doesn't work ! Oh, a moment... let me recheck again

Comment: No no ! It doesn't work !

Comment: you need to do a set and reset `.seasonbar  a {/* set */}
.seasonbar ~ .seasonbar a {/* reset */}`

Comment: If `.seasonbar:first-child *` doesn't work it is probably because there is an element before the first `div` otherwise it should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.seasonbar:first-child > a`

```css
.seasonbar:first-child > a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="seasonbar">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div class="seasonbar">
  <a href="#">E 1</a>
  <a href="#">E 2</a>
  <a href="#">E 3</a>
</div>
```